# How to find max value in PHP array between the first 10 elements then from next 10 elements and so on?

Tags: php

In PHP array having 1000 elements. What I want is to find 'max value' between first 10 elements. Then need to find max value from next 10 elements and process goes on till I reach at the end of array.

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,15,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,22,42,33,34,35,36,37,38,11,10]
```

expected output :
15,10,42

Comment: Why did you tag this with Javascript?

Comment: Anyway, without doing your homework for you, want you want to do is use the `array_slice` function and iterate over each section of the array - get a slice, sort it, and then get the last value. Until you reach the end of the array.

Comment: Alternatively, use `array_slice` as above but use the `max` function, as in `$largest = max($arr);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in several ways. If this is an assignement, counting and looping will help you understand the logic needed, but you can get this done using builtin functions in a rather compact way:

- [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) applies a given function to every element of an array and returns a new array.
- [`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) splits an array containing the number of elements specified.
- [`max`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) returns the largest value of an array.

Putting it all together:

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,15,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,22,42,33,34,35,36,37,38,11,10];

$max = array_map('max', array_chunk($array, 10));
```

Answer (score 1):

With some logic:

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,15,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,22,42,33,34,35,36,37,38,11,10];

$lengthOfArray = count($array);
$maxValues = [];
$groupBy = 10;
$tempMaxValue = -1; // A small value that can be comparable


//Loop the array
for ($i=0; $i < $lengthOfArray; $i++) { 

  if($tempMaxValue<$array[$i]){
     $tempMaxValue= $array[$i];
  }


  // If we passed 10 results:
  if($i%$groupBy==9){
     $maxValues[] = $tempMaxValue; //Hold the Max
     $tempMaxValue = -1;           //Reset the temp value
  }
}
```

**$maxValues** will contain all the results.